# Вывести категорию к посту single-postfolio.php

Tags: wordpress

Решил добавить вывод название категории к посту , `var_dump` выводит null.
всё делаю на single-portfolio.php

```
<div class="site-content">
        <?php
            if ( have_posts() )
            {
                while ( have_posts() )
                {
                    the_post();
                    the_title();
                    the_content();
                }
            }
            $current_category = single_cat_title('', false);
            var_dump($current_category);
            echo 'Category: ' . single_cat_title( '', false);

        ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress. Или взять любую нормальную тему и посмотреть правильную реализацию

Comment: sibgle_cat_title и wp_get_post_categories - это для категорий постов. У вас кастомный тип записей. И скорее всего таксономия кастомная. Пробуйте wp_get_post_terms(). Или single_term_title(). Но там зависит от ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Функция `single_cat_title()` работает только на страницах архива, а вы пытаетесь её использовать на странице поста кастомного типа (портфолио).

Вам нужна функция `wp_get_post_categories()`, которая возвращает список всех категорий данного поста в виде массива. Вызвать её нужно так:

```
$cats = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: всё равно нулл выводит. Я это пытался

Comment: так, что то не понял...заюзал ```$cats = wp_get_post_categories( the_ID() );
                    var_dump($cats);``` id  он написал , а вар думп всеравно нулл

Comment: Ну почему вы делаете не пойми что? Вы в документацию хоть раз посмотрите, а не пишите в код, что в голову придет. Функция the_ID() выводит на экран id поста и возвращает null. Ясное дело, wp_get_post_categories() не выведет категории для null. Вам нужна `get_the_ID()`, которая возвращает id поста и не выводит ничего на экран. Этот id попадет в wp_get_post_categories(), которая вернёт в $cats массив. И тогда уж выводите var_dump( $cats )

Comment: get_the_ID() не работает тоже . Я это первое пробовал и он тоже выводит null wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID() )  . Я первое дело что сделал , так это посмотрел в документацию и видел этот get_the_ID и плюс я его уже один раз использовал , поэтому и я удевлён  что и это выводит null поэтому я уже и попробовал the_ID

Comment: sibgle_cat_title и wp_get_post_categories  - это для категорий постов. У вас кастомный тип записей. И скорее всего таксономия кастомная. Пробуйте wp_get_post_terms(). Или single_term_title(). Но там зависит от ситуации.

Comment: Дайте адрес сайта, посмотрю на классы body и поскажу точнее.

Comment: @Ivan на localhost заходи :D

Comment: @XXXXXX Хахаха, смешная шутка. Но я вам по делу написал до этого. У вас тип записи portfolio. Функции, которые вы до этого пытались применить, не будут для него работать.

Comment: @XXXXXX И на ты не очень вежливо переходить без разрешения. Особенно когда просишь помощи.

Comment: @Ivan про посты я понял